# Perl die (and stop the whole program) in a thread

Tags: multithreading, perl, die

I have a Perl script that spawns a group of worker threads.  When one of these threads encounters a fatal error I would like the ENTIRE script to die and print an error message.

The problem is... when you use die in a thread it will only terminate the current thread with a message like `Thread 42 terminated abnormally: blah blah blah...` and the rest of the script will continue to run.

---

**Example:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;

# Create threads
for my $i (1 .. 5) {
    threads->create(\&do_something, $i);
}

# Wait for all threads to complete
$_->join() for threads->list();

sub do_something {
    my $i = shift;
    die "I'm died" if $i == 3;
}
```

**Output:**

> Thread 3 terminated abnormally: I'm died at line 15

---

How can I make a fatal error in a thread kill the whole script?

Answer (score 4):

According to [perldoc threads](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html#EXITING-A-THREAD):

> Calling [exit EXPR](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exit.html) inside a thread causes the whole application to terminate. Because of this, the use of `exit()` inside threaded code, or in modules that might be used in threaded applications, is strongly discouraged.
>
> If `exit()` really is needed, then consider using the following:
>
> ```
> threads->exit() if threads->can('exit');   # Thread friendly
> exit(status);
> ```

Comment: just calling exit does work, but it prints an ugly "Program terminated with running threads" error.  Is there a way to kill all threads and exit cleanly?